# How to access isolated 'this' scope in angular directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

If I use $scope, this directive works perfectly:

```
function alertBox(){
  return {
    template: 
      '<div ng-show="alert" class="alert alert-{{alert.type}}" style="text-align: center;">\
         <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">x</a>\
         <span ng-bind-html="alert.message | safe_html"></span>\
       </div>'
  }
}
```

The alert is defined in my controller as:

```
$scope.alert = {message: 'test!', type: 'danger'};
```

And my simple view:

```
<div alert-box></div>
```

However, I don't use $scope and instead have my alert defined using 'this':

```
this.alert = {message: 'test!', type: 'danger'};
```

But no matter what I try I can't figure out how to inject the value of 'this' into the directive.

Ideally I would be able to reference 'self.alert' or something, so that I don't have to define the scope context as an attribute, but assuming I do, I've tried variations of this to no avail:

```
function alertBox(){
    return {
        scope: {
            scope: '=scope'
        },
        template: '<div ng-show="' + scope + '.alert" class="alert alert-' + scope + '.type" style="text-align: center;"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">x</a>        <span ng-bind-html="' + scope + '.message | safe_html"></span></div>'
    }
}
```

And my html:

```
<div alert-box scope="welcome"></div>
```

In that example I've got `'WelcomeController as welcome'` defined.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a working version of the sample code with the problem, somewhere like StackOverflow snippets, Plunker, JSFiddle?

Comment: Sure, if I don't get a quick answer I'll follow up with a working example. Seems like a straightforward issue though, no?

Comment: @FloydPink here's a fiddle showing what I'm trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/jgentes/s58chtsv/1/

Comment: You should read about the concept of [scope for a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive). Yours just uses the scope of its parent, and so, it has to assume that `alert` is defined in that scope. Similarly, with controllerAs, the controller instance `welcome` is published on the scope, and so then, you could change your template to `welcome.alert.message`, but as before it would not be very reusable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues of misunderstanding here.

**First**, directives with their own templates typically use an isolated scope, such that the scope under which the template operates is different than the scope where the directive operates. That is what makes a directive reusable.

In your original example, the directive uses the parent scope (with implicit `scope: false`) and not isolate scope (`scope: {}`).

**Second**, you're attempting to use the "controller as" approach and define your `alert` object as a property of the controller instance. The controller instance (what you refer to as `this`) is then published on the scope under the controller alias - `welcome` in your example. So, instead of `{{alert.message}}` you'd need to use `{{welcome.alert.message}}`. That's all that "controller as" does - puts "this" (i.e. the controller instance object) as `$scope.<alias>`.

So (and still), the same principles of scope, as in my first point, apply.

===

In order to make your example work, create a directive with isolate scope and bind the object `alert` via attribute binding.

Here's the canonical (although wasteful, see below) way that that this is done:

```
.directive("alertBox", function(){
  return {  
    scope: {
      alert: "="
    },
    template: '<div ng-show="alert" class="alert-{{alert.type}}">{{alert.message}}</div>'
  };
})
```

Usage:

```
<div ng-controller="WelcomeController as welcome">
  <div alert-box alert="welcome.alert"></div>
</div>
```

```
// in WelcomeController
this.alert = {message: 'test!', type: 'danger'};
```

The template of the directive is not impacted by how the passed-in `alert` object is set on the scope.

**Bonus section**

So, why wasteful?

The `"="` scope binding creates a two-way binding, which is likely unnecessary here, since it is not expected that the directive `alertBox` would modify the `alert` object on the parent. A two-way binding sets 2 $watchers, one of which is unused and thus wasteful.

Instead, you could use the `"&"` one-way binding to an expression. `"&"` gives a function that needs to be invoked to get the object returned by the bound expression (rather than the object directly as with `"="`), so the directive's template changes slightly to:

```
scope: {
  alert: "&",
},
template: '<div ng-show="alert()" class="alert-{{alert().type}}">{{alert().message}}</div>'
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I thought about using '&' but certainly would have got hung up on not using it as a function. Thanks for that too.

Answer (score -1):

**bindToController:** You can use bindToController property which when set to true in a directive with scope isolated, the components properties are bound to `controller` rather than `scope`, which makes it available on `this`.

Typically you would do something like this when using `controller as` syntax.

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function () {
    this.name = "Vinoth Babu";
});

myapp.directive('alertBox', function(){    
    return {
        controller: 'MainCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        template: '<div>{{ctrl.name}}</div>'
    };    
});
```

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
        <div alert-box></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SNF9x/136/

Please do let me if you have something else in your mind.

Comment: Thanks @Thalaivar, this looks great, but what if I'm using the directive in multiple controllers? This seems to bind the directive only to 'MainCtrl'.

Comment: I see - in your fiddle you omit the "controller: 'MainCtrl'" line, which is what I was confused by.

Comment: It looks like your fiddle didn't work, here's an example of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/jgentes/s58chtsv/1/

Comment: `bindToController` doesn't work without a child or isolate scope. Also, with `controller: "MainCtrl"`, you are creating yet another instance of the "MainCtrl" controller. I think you misunderstand what controller the  `bindToController` refers to

Comment: @NewDev: I agree it does not work in isolate scope, but it does work when you want to explicitly inherit from your parent controller with scope: true defined... in this case you can take advantage of bindToController... http://jsfiddle.net/s58chtsv/2/

Comment: Again - you are misunderstanding what `bindToController` does. `bindToController` refers to directive's controller, which is not even present in your last fiddle. / @JamesGentes